# Gutenberg Block showing invalid content on edit

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, block-editor

**My requirement**: I am trying to create a simple gutenberg block which will have a `textarea` and a `dropdown`. Once a user has provided the details I want to save it as a **shortcode** in DB, but when the user come to edit the block it should show the content in `textarea` and selected item in `dropdown`.

**The issue** that I am getting, on create everything is working as expected, but when I come to edit screen the content is getting messed up. Also the dropdown is not showing for existing block.

Here is the code that I have written with the help of [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/) & [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/337789/103815) article.

```js
const {__} = wp.i18n;
const {RawHTML} = wp.element;
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;
const {PanelBody, SelectControl, TextareaControl} = wp.components;
const {InspectorControls} = wp.editor;

const blockStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#900',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: '20px',
};
const countries = [
    {label: __('Select a countries', 'txtdomain'), value: ''},
    {label: 'India', value: 'IND'},
    {label: 'United States of America', value: 'USA'},
    {label: 'Sri Lanka', value: 'LKA'}
];

registerBlockType('myplugin/example-01-block', {
    title: 'My Plugin',
    icon: 'editor-code',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: "string",
            source: "text",
            default: '// Place your text here!',
        },
        country: {
            type: "string",
            default: ""
        },
    },
    example: {},

    edit: (props) => {
        const {
            attributes: {content},
            setAttributes,
            className,
            country
        } = props;

        return (
                <div className={ className }>
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody
                            title={ __('My Plugin Settings', 'txtdomain') }
                            >
                            <SelectControl
                                label={ __('Country', 'txtdomain') }
                                value={ country }
                                options={ countries }
                                onChange={ value => setAttributes({country: value}) }
                                />
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                
                    <TextareaControl
                        value={ content }
                        onChange={ value => setAttributes({content: value}) }
                        /> 
                </div>
                );
    },
    save: (props) => {
        const {
            attributes: {content, country}
        } = props;
        var myShortcode = '[myshortcode country="' + country + '", text="' + content + '"]';
        return (
                <div>
                    <RawHTML>{ myShortcode }</RawHTML>
                </div>
                );
    }
})
```

On Create for first time
[image: When I add block]

When editing the created block in next time.
[image: When I come to edit screen]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is the following part, whereby you set the attribute *source* to [`text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#text) which means (after the block/post is saved) the editor will read the value from the inner text of the div returned by your `save` function:

```js
attributes: {
    content: {
        type: "string",
        source: "text", // this shouldn't be "text"
        default: '// Place your text here!',
    },
```

So if the `save` function returned an element with the HTML `<div>[myshortcode country="IND", text="Hello World!"]</div>`, then with the above attribute settings, the `content` value would be `[myshortcode country="IND", text="Hello World!"]` which explains why this happened:

[image: Block error preview]

So you should just omit the `source` property there, i.e. do not specify the attribute source, and just let the editor stores the attribute value in the block [comment delimiter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/key-concepts/#data-attributes).

### Other Issues in your code

1. `wp.editor.InspectorControls` is deprecated and use `wp.blockEditor.InspectorControls` instead. So use `const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;`.
2. In your `edit` function, `country` should be part of the `attributes` like so:

   ```js
   const {
       attributes: {content, country}, // "country" belongs here
       setAttributes,
       className,
       country                         // NOT HERE, so remove this.
   } = props;
   ```
3. There's an unwanted `,` (comma) in your shortcode (`[myshortcode country="' + country + '", text=...`), so you should remove that comma.

Comment: You are superstar, I spend almost 3-4days trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Chears!

Comment: can you also help me as how to add a custom class in my block, so then on create or edit that's get appended so I can add css rules.

Comment: You could do it like what you did in your `edit` function: `<div className={ className + ' foo-bar my-class' }>` ? But you should consider using the `useBlockProps` hook introduced in the [block API version 2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/). However, if you need further assistance with that, please ask in another question. :)

Comment: Sorry I forget to update my comment, I archived it using `useBlockProps`. Thank you once again. :)